# How do i load html file in WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have on my hard disk an html file i saved the content from a website with Webclient.

```
private void DownloadHtml()
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile(webSite, OriginalHtmlFilePath);
            }
        }
```

Now after did some changes with the file content changed only some texts no tags or any scripts i want to load back the html file. So i did:

```
string html = File.ReadAllText(ScrambledHtmlFilePath);
            Uri Uri = new Uri(ScrambledHtmlFilePath);
            //webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(Uri);
```

In both cases using the html or the Uri its loading the html as local file and therefore im getting some scripts errors.

If i open the file from my hard disk with Chrome or IE it's loading the file online like i surfed to the site im not getting any script errors.
The problem is that when im using Chrome or IE its taking like 10-15 seconds untill its loading the file.

How can i load the html file in WebBrowser fast and to be online like if i was openning it with IE or Chrome ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) property of the `WebBrowser` control to the edited-HTML content.